# How to implement a custom way to lock/unlock an android mobile phone

Tags: android, security

Is it possible to implement a custom way to lock/unlock an android mobile phone?

I know that in versions 2.1 from android and before, there was only the locking pattern available, and that in version 2.2 it is now possible to set a password as well, but what if i want to make a custom way of locking/unlocking it myself (such as recognizing handwriting, or making some different alternative method for the locking and unlocking process) ?

Is it possible to achieve this through an application? or would it be necessary to make a version of the Android OS based in the same source code but with changes within it?

If it would be necessary to make a different custom version of Android, can anyone give me any hints or tips as to how and where in the source code files are the blocking options considered?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Miguel: "Is it possible to achieve this through an application?" -- not at this time. Eventually, it may be, as there has been some discussions of making this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for mylockforandroid  at googlecode..as fas I know source worked for those devices before 2.1

Answer (score 0):

These days finger unlock and face recognition are also in trend to unlock Android phones. But, there is no app to custom your own locking and unlocking process.

But you can unlock the phone for switching network carrier manually by following some easy instructions:

Identify your device's IMEI number by dialing *#06# on your smartphone.

Share the IMEI number at Unlock Unit to receive an unlock code for your smartphone.

Use this unlock code to unlock your [Huawei P20 Fast and Easy](https://www.unlockunit.com/unlock-huawei-p20-092485) and feel free to use whichever network carrier you want.